# Path to sheet on a workbook over IP address?

Tags: excel, path, ip-address, excel-2010, vba

I want to update my sheet with content from another sheet on another workbook. That workbook is in shared `SharedFolder` on a network. So, I'll be using `FormulaR1C1` to reference that sheet.

Currently that sheet is on the same workbook and I'm referencing to it like this:

```
.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC2,BE!C1:C15,3,FALSE),"""")"
```

If content of my current sheet is in workbook in `SharedFolder` how could I reference to it over `IP` address?

I'm able to do this, which is similar to scenario that I need:

[image]

here I'm referencing to an excel file on mapped network drive(Z:). As you can see this is done through formula bar. I need something like this but in `VBA` and over `IP` address.

Thanks.

Comment: thats a good question but I do not think its possible within a formula.

Comment: @mehow Thanks on upvote. I've updated my question if you could look at it now and see can it be used for some kind of solution.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/sheets.htm). I get a feeling you're over-complicating your current problem. What is it exactly that you want to do? Can you please be more specific in your explanation? It sounds to me like you are trying to get a data out of a workbook by specifying the location to that workbook via an IP address. Im not sure if thats the case but at least it sounds like it

Comment: @mehow That's right what I tying to do: "to get a data out of a workbook by specifying the location to that workbook via an IP address". Is it possible?

Comment: ha! if that was possible then anybody would be able to access any file from any IP!? crazy. I dont think thats possible without establishing a proper connection or an authorized mapping system, some firewall unblocking etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to replace the share drive letter (z:\ in your example above) with an address. For example I can reference a file on my C drive in the following way in a vlookup formula.

```
VLOOKUP(RC2,'\\localhost\Users\Me\[source.xlsx]Sheet1'!B2:C7,2,FALSE)
```

Assuming your problem is that your file is on a file server but you have not mapped it to a drive letter then you should be able to find the name of the file server or just use the IP address.

e.g.

```
\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\filepath1\filepath2\[filename.xlsx]
```

or

```
\\fileservername\filepath1\filepath2\[filename.xlsx]
```

Comment: I had something like this in my mind! This is actually working, but partially! Whats happening is that every time it comes to the vlookup formula I get openfiledialog for update values. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: hmmm .. I saw the same behaviour when I did not have the correct path. Note the file path should start with two \ characters. It was not showing up correctly before in my answer.